# Condition on a last iteration of loop in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have a list of emails I need to loop through and display in this format.

```
  renderEmaillist() {
    return this.props.OfficeEmailAddress.map((officeEmail) => {
        return (
          <a key={emailID} href={`mailto:${officeEmail}`}>{officeEmail}{'; '}</a>
          );
    });
}
```

When its rendered

```
 email@mail.com; email2@mail.com;
```

I want to remove the semicolon at the end of the last loop only.

What is the bets way to do this?

Comment: You _could_ technically add the semicolon in css instead of javascript theoretically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have access to the index and the full array from within [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
return this.props.OfficeEmailAddress.map((officeEmail, index, arr) => {
  return (
    <a key={emailID} href={`mailto:${officeEmail}`}>
      {officeEmail}{index === arr.length - 1 ? '' : '; '}
    </a>
  );
});
```

I added a ternary to determine if we are on the last element of the array and, if we are, to just output an empty string.

Comment: @ZenaMesfin, did you add it to your function parameters?